# how to draw pythagoras tree

Tags: java, swing, fractals

How to draw pythagoras tree in swing ?
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/PythagorasTree_825.gif

Answer (score 1):

Well, in this case, you won't use Swing, but rather [Java2D](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/index.html)